# Connection between parabolic and elliptic PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I am trying to verify the well-posedness of some PDEs which I solve numerically. There is a paper which proves the well-posedness of a similar problem using Ladyzhenskaya's book on hyperbolic problems. In particular, it uses Section 6, Chapter V to show that an equation of the form

$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{a}\left( \mathbf{x},\rho,\nabla \rho \right) + a\left(\mathbf{x},t,\nabla \rho,\rho \right) = 0$,

is well-posed.

If that problem is well-posed, is it also true that

$- \nabla \cdot \mathbf{a}\left( \mathbf{x},\rho,\nabla \rho \right) + a\left(\mathbf{x},\nabla \rho,\rho \right) = 0$

is well-posed?

Can you please give me either a proof or where to look for the result. I suspect that there is such a result in Ladyzhenskaya's book on elliptic problems, but I am away from my university, so I don't have direct access to it right now. I appreciate any help you can provide in finding this result.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you also give you your definition of well-posedness?

Comment: In this case, I am happy to have existence and uniqueness of a "classical solution for smooth initial data" since that is what the paper that I found gives.

Comment: The paper that I am trying to base my result on is "Generalized Forchheimer Flow in Porous Media" by Douglas, Paes-Leme, and Giorgi.